# How is eclipse feature to generate sample xml from an xsd schema implemented?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd

I'm curious how eclipse implements generating xml from an xsd schema, as described here:

http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftcrexxsd.html

Is the source code available to view, to try and understand how this function is implemented?

Comment: Eclipse source is available from the git repositories at https://git.eclipse.org/c/ and can also be installed as part of Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wizard for `Generate -> XML File` is 
the [`org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.wizards.NewXMLWizard`](https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.sourceediting/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui/src-wizards/org/eclipse/wst/xml/ui/internal/wizards/NewXMLWizard.java) class.
The generator under the hood is the [`org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.wizards.NewXMLGenerator`](https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.sourceediting/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui/src-wizards/org/eclipse/wst/xml/ui/internal/wizards/NewXMLGenerator.java) class.
They are part of the
[`org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui`](https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.sourceediting/tree/master/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui) plugin. Just follow the links to see the sources.